# Ooyala player version 2 or 3 not running in IE 10 metro mode

Tags: ooyala

Ooyala player version 2 or 3 not running in IE 10 metro mode
Only in metro mode of IE 10 below code is not running.
Pls help. 
below is the code used.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://player.ooyala.com/player.js?width=750&height=312&embedCode=4yb2NyNToSgl-L6mEJvDW4NaqxRYQvnN">
</script>
<head>

<!-- Load Ooyala Player -->
       <script src='http://player.ooyala.com/v3/4yb2NyNToSgl-L6mEJvDW4NaqxRYQvnN'></script>

</head>
<body>
<!-- Player Placement -->
<div id='playerwrapper' style='width:750px;height:312px;'></div>
<script>
    var videoPlayer = OO.Player.create('playerwrapper', '4yb2NyNToSgl-L6mEJvDW4NaqxRYQvnN');
    videoPlayer.play();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not seeing playback in IE10 metro for a couple of reasons- you are not embedding player v3 correctly, so the v2 player is the only one thats being loaded.  V2 does not support metro in IE10 unless your site is whitelisted for Flash.

I've fixed up your test page for you, please insert an embed code and your player branding id as provided by your Account Manager.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Untitled Page</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='http://player.ooyala.com/v3/{PLAYER BRANDING ID}'></script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Player Placement -->
<div id='playerwrapper' style='width:750px;height:312px;'></div>
<script>
OO.ready(function() {
  var videoPlayer = OO.Player.create('playerwrapper', '{EMBED CODE}');
  videoPlayer.play();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```