# HTML OOYALA player issue in ie10 metro mode

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, html5-video, ooyala

I have seen someone posted a question in stack overflow titled

[Ooyala player version 2 or 3 not running in IE 10 metro mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496358/ooyala-player-version-2-or-3-not-running-in-ie-10-metro-mode)

and suggested answer was

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Untitled Page</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='http://player.ooyala.com/v3/{PLAYER BRANDING ID}'></script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Player Placement -->
<div id='playerwrapper' style='width:750px;height:312px;'></div>
<script>
OO.ready(function() {
  var videoPlayer = OO.Player.create('playerwrapper', '{EMBED CODE}');
  videoPlayer.play();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a similar problem.

- I have used with proper id's.
- created a sample html file
- deployed it in iis7 web server.
- set all mime types (.mp4 etc)

It works fine in win8 desktop mode, but when I access this in IE10 metro mode it shows the following message:

```
You need to have adobe flash player to view this content
```

From ooyala support I have gotten a sample html url (same code-published in their server) which is almost the same code in the above answer.  Surprisingly it runs without flash in ie10 metro mode.

When I open page view source their page code and mine have no difference.
Only difference is web server.

What am I missing here? Any IIS server settings?

Comment: @ SNA, Feel free to post this issue in the Ooyala community. Our support team is there to help answer questions. http://community.ooyala.com/ Best,
Thomas

Comment: http://aspspider.info/swapnamc/default.aspx
 please check this website i hosted public .tHis has the same code publish in .net environment asp.net 3.5 and iis

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any differences when our player is embedded on a page hosted by IIS.  We can help troubleshoot this if we can get a link to the page that is breaking, please post it here or file a ticket at http://support.ooyala.com/users/contact

Comment: http://aspspider.info/swapnamc/default.aspx
 please check this website i hosted public .tHis has the same code publish in .net environment asp.net 3.5 and iis

Comment: What is your test environment? I cannot reproduce the issue in IE10 metro.  You can also try to remove the platform param from the V3 embed.

Comment: Our tested environement details:-
Environment win8 metro mode .
We have a oracle VM virtual box. win8(Windows8-ReleasePreview-32bit-English) installed.
Also tested in windows 8 Enterprize one release before RTM (real machine not VM)
and also platform removed.http://aspspider.info/swapnamc/test.html